# How to convert a shelve object into a dictionary object in Python

Tags: python, shelve

I have a persistent dictionary created with `DB = shelve.open('Database')`

This object is of type:

> class 'shelve.DbfilenameShelf'

However, I want to know if it is possible to convert it back into a dictionary:

> class 'dict'

PS: I know I can just use the shelve object as I would a normal dictionary, but I want to explicitly convert it from a shelve to a dictionary.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just use the builtin class constructor `dict`:

```
DB_as_dict = dict(DB)
```

Note that this only creates a copy of the information stored in the DB, so changes to the dict will not affect the file.